# Autowire repositories from similar tables in different datasources

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have two versions of the same application. They are using similar database schemas. I want to run a junit test that compares two tables on both sides. I am using Springboot and JPA. I can autowire both datasources in the same test. I can autowire a CrudRepository for one of the tables in the primary datasource. But how can I autowire a similar repository for the same table that is sitting on the second datasource, at the same time in the same Junit test? I would like to do something like this on the same class:

```
@Autowired( Datasource="primarydatasource")
CustomerRepository fistCustomerRepository;

@Autowired( Datasource="seconddatasource")
CustomerRepository secondCustomerRepository;
```

I have checked many tutorials and answers here, but I have not found a clear example on this.

Answer (score 0):

[Using multiple datasources with Spring Boot](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7)

Answer (score 0):

You can create two EntityManager

```
@Bean("em1")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em1(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder
            .dataSource(customDataSource1())
            .packages(DataSource.class)
            .build();
}

@Bean("em2")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em2(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return ...;
}
```

Then you can inject the entity manager in you repository

```
    @Repository
    class CustomerRepositoryOracle{
        @PersistenceContext(name="em1")
        private EntityManager entityManager;
    }

    @Repository
    class CustomerRepositoryPostgreSQL{
        @PersistenceContext(name="em2")
        private EntityManager entityManager;
    }
```

Comment: Should I create two classes for the repositories, even if the schema is exactly the same? And how do I express that one is linked to the first datasource, and the other to the second datasource? In your example I can not see how to know that. Thanks

Comment: If schema are same create a abstract class and pass the entity manager from child class,  @PersistenceContext(name="em1")
    private EntityManager entityManager;